# Normal map is way screwy!

Tags: uv, normal-map

I have generated a normal map for my (unwrapped) model in Blender 4.0.2 The Normal map appears corrupted (big green streak from the lower left corner as you can see) and I can't figure out why. I have done the regular UV Unwrap, Smart UV Unwrap, Project from View, etc, but nothing seems to fix this. I have already merged vertices by distance and the Face Orientation appears correct both inside the crate and outside. When I generate the Normal map for the lid of this crate, it comes out fine. Any idea what I'm overlooking?
[image: With unwrap info visible]
[image: normal only]
Many thanks in advance!

Here is a link to the FBX file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Jeyqheow4gCunPqS9Pl6JT9VIuoim_YU/view?usp=sharing

---

I ended up just deleting the darned model and recreating it from sratch. I really appreciate those of you that commented! After losing a day of productivity, I decided I'm better off recreating it rather than trying to figure out what was wrong, lol.

Comment: Hello, hard to say without the object, maybe share the object. Or you could simply paint over the bad areas with a correct color in order to get rid of these bad streaks?

Comment: Thanks. Good point abut the object.  I'll post the FBX version of it.

Comment: Post the .blend, not the fbx.  From right before you hit the "bake" button.  The fbx won't let us know why it's wrong-- likely, we'll just bake it right and be unable to reproduce your problem.  This particular case looks like you baked to a different UV map than the one you're showing, or that you have parts of your geometry that you're not showing, but a .blend file would let us say for sure.

Comment: Yeah, it's not corrupted, because Blender did exactly what you wanted it to do :) Seems like a common geometry problem, likely a few vertices (given the shape of the 'triangle') that were wrongly selected. You can find those by enabling the sync option in the UV unwrapping area, selecting all vertices on your mesh, and then selecting the culprits by zooming in on the area in the lower left corner.